# Run an Angular function only after a client-side input validation

Tags: angularjs

I have a function 'loadNewChannel()' that now runs when any value is typed in the input field. I want to run it only when the value is validated through a basic client-side list.

I found [this](http://plnkr.co/edit/ghdtdYruQaaO0Yxxlrt1?p=preview) which should cover my needs but I'm not sure how to implement it as a condition for the function to fire.

ANGULAR SCRIPT

```
var Channelinput = 'no-layout-archive';
var app = angular.module('arenaApp', ['ngResource', 'ngSanitize', 'infinite-scroll']);

app.controller('channelShow', function($scope, $resource) { 
  var Channel = $resource('http://api.are.na/v2/channels/:slug');

  var channel = Channel.get({slug: Channelinput, sort: 'position', direction: 'asc'}, function(){
            $scope.channel = channel;
          });

    $scope.loadNewChannel = function(){
                var channel = Channel.get({slug: 'no-layout-premium-archive', sort: 'position', direction: 'desc'}, function(){
                $scope.channel = channel;
    });
  }
})
```

HTML

```
<input placeholder="passcode" onfocus="this.placeholder = ' '" onblur="this.placeholder = 'passcode'" ng-keyup="loadNewChannel()" >
```

I'm aware it's not a secure system but it's for a small beta, that's not an issue. Live link (click "Access the premium" to visualize the input field): http://nolayout.com/archive

Any help welcome, thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if the validation happens on the client side and it is a custom one, you could try something like this:

```
var Channelinput = 'no-layout-archive';
var app = angular.module('arenaApp', ['ngResource', 'ngSanitize', 'infinite-scroll']);

app.controller('channelShow', function($scope, $resource) {
    var Channel = $resource('http://api.are.na/v2/channels/:slug');

    var channel = Channel.get({ slug: Channelinput, sort: 'position', direction: 'asc' }, function() {
        $scope.channel = channel;
    });

    $scope.loadNewChannel = function() {
        var channel = Channel.get({ slug: 'no-layout-premium-archive', sort: 'position', direction: 'desc' }, function() {
            $scope.channel = channel;
        });
    };

    $scope.passcode = '';

    function validatePasscode(code) {
        // put validation logic here, return true or false
        return code == "somevalidpasscode";
    }

    $scope.$watch('passcode', function(value) {
        var isValid = validatePasscode(value);

        if (isValid) {
            $scope.loadNewChannel();
        }
    });
});
```

And your input would lose the keyup event and have the ng-model attribute:

```
<input placeholder="passcode" onfocus="this.placeholder = ' '" onblur="this.placeholder = 'passcode'" ng-model="passcode" >
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Thank you. If you have the patience of showing me a very simple validation logic example that could work there (like passcode === 'secretword' returns true) it would be great, I tried but can't make it work, I'm newbie with angular.

Comment: No problem at all... actually, inside the validatePasscode function there is no angular, it's just javascript, I've edited the answer with an example, please let me know if it works.